# Not able to upload file using NestJs and Multer

Tags: file-upload, nestjs, multer

I am trying to upload files to aws s3 bucket using Nestjs

```
  @Post('uploadfile/:bucketName')
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
  async addAvatar(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File, @Param('bucketName') bucketName: string): Promise<S3.ManagedUpload.SendData> {
    return this.s3ManagerService.uploadFile(file.buffer, file.originalname, bucketName);
  }
```

and my Postrequest is:

```
    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("file", fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, `./uploads/${uploadedFileName}.jpg`)), file.data.originalname);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(formData.getHeaders()));

    const response = await axios.post("my_url", formData, {
      ...formData.getHeaders(),
    });
```

Getting an error always :

*[Nest] 5082  - 14/09/2021, 19:36:48   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined*

Could you please help me if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

It indicates that your file is not uploaded, Probably because it is expected to be send as multipart/formData. Try this instead:

```js
    const response = await axios.post("my_url", formData, {
        headers: {
            "content-type": "multipart/form-data"
        },
    });
```